# How to make overlay div in foundation 4

Tags: zurb-foundation

Sometimes when you check a website, you can find half-transparent div hanging above another div (or image). Like in a sport website, they lay a panel of sport score over an image.

Can I also achieve this using Foundation 4?

The example just looks like the JS component Orbit's bottom, where you can see a half-black div with words on top, while at the same time being able to see the picture.

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html

Comment: What is an example site/feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this effect buy using **relative** and **absolute** positioning in css. Here is an example:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex

to make div transparent check:

[Transparent background on DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732019/transparent-background-on-div)

Comment: Good idea..but you know if you add relative or absolute attribute, you will break their default grid system (: